# How do I Insert records in database multiple Tables using winforms c#

Tags: c#

I have a winform which i have attached here.. When i Insert record in Customer table, I also want to add the record in the orderlineitems table in my database as of which the record in the Order table will also be inserted.
I have inserted the record in Customer table but when i insert record in OrderLineItems table, it shows an error.

I also wanted to ask that, my OrderLineItems Table in database contains columns as :

1. ID(pk)
2. OrderID(pk)
3. Quantity
4. Particular
5. Rates
6. Status

On my Form, I have only quantity, particular and rates fields from which i can get their values but i dont have Status and Orderid values on my winform. how do i get the values of status and orderId then?

My Code is:

```
private void buttonInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string SQL = String.Format("Insert into Customer values ('{0}','{1}','{2}')", textBoxName.Text, textBoxContactNo.Text, textBoxAddress.Text);
        //string SQL1 = String.Format("Insert into Order values ({0},'{1}','{2}',{3})",);
        DataManagementClass dm = new DataManagementClass();

    int result = dm.ExecuteActionQuery(SQL);
    if (result > 0)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < recordsDataGridView.RowCount ; i++)
        {
            string query = String.Format("Insert into OrderLineItems values({0},'{1}','{2}','{3}',{4})",7,QuantityColumn, ParticularColumn, RatesColumn,1);
            dm.ExecuteActionQuery(query);
        }
        //string query = String.Format("Insert into OrderLineItems values ('{0}','{1},'{2}'

    }
```

What am i doing wrong here. please guide me the correct way.
Thanx..
 [image: WinForm Image]

Comment: what error is it showing? any reason you cannot use LINQ to SQL by the way?

Comment: Let's hope `textBoxName.Text` doesn't contain value `' OR 1=1; DROP TABLE Customer;--`

Comment: it shows string value can not be converted into int

Answer (score 2):

Suggest a few enhancements to get your business logic working and maintainable:

- write a stored procedure for your `CreateCustomer` and `CreateLineItem` routines in your database.
- use a SqlCommand and its Parameters collection. Stop whatever you're doing right now and guard against SQL injection.
- remove all this code from the button click event.
- create new methods like `CreateCustomer` and `CreateLineItems`. Call these method from your button click handler method.

```
 private void buttonInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   int result = CreateCustomer(textBoxName.Text.Trim(),
                               textBoxContactNo.Text.Trim(),
                               textBoxAddress.Text.Trim());
    if (result > 0)
    {
       foreach(var row in recordsDataGridView.Rows)
       {
           CreateLineItem(quantity, particulars, rates);
       }
    }
```

Comment: p.campell, i dont know why do i scare from stored procedures, may b i dont know how to do work by using them. i will definitely learn to use storedprocedures.

Answer (score 1):

You are inserting values like this: '{1}','{2}','{3}'

This leads me to assume you are inserting string values.
If there is an apostroph in your string values, it will cause a syntax error.
Try

```
yourstring.replace("'", "''")
```

on the arguments.

Also, do as p.campbell suggest..
Use parameters to prevent SQL injection..
Somebody might malicously take advantage of your code's open security holes..